# swift read xls(excel) content + Hindi + Gujarati Character Encoding issue

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, encoding, read.csv

read xls(Excel) file with non english character(**not xlsx file)

i have tried all the encoding option but i am unable to read xls file content.

```
let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)// Document Directory file path
let dataEncoded = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```

Example
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show an extract of the data you are trying to read, and some (complete) code that you use to read the data. See also  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I meant to say, show a `sample` of the data, so we can test various options.

Comment: Note, instead of trying to read an `Excel.xls` file, convert it to `csv`, then read it. It is **much** easier that way.

Comment: the link does not work, it is not `https`, it is not secure. Just show an example of the data in your post (a few lines will do)

Comment: looks simple enough. Have you tried converting the `.xls` file to `csv` and reading that, one line at a time?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine my business logic is to download zip file and unzipped programatically and read that xls file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved my issue through below SDK:

https://github.com/QuetzalMX/QuetzalXLSReader